# This solver needs samples of at least 2 classes in the data, but the data contains only one class: 1

Tags: python

```
# Create Logistic Regression model and train it with our train data
classifier = LogisticRegression(solver = "liblinear", random_state = 0)
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
### ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

### <ipython-input-207-01f1e57d6e65> in <module>
      
### 1 # Create Logistic Regression model and train it with our train data

### 2 classifier = LogisticRegression(solver = "liblinear", random_state = 0)

### ----> 3 classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

### ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\_logistic.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
###    1354                               " 'solver' is set to 'liblinear'. Got 'n_jobs'"
###    1355                               " = {}.".format(effective_n_jobs(self.n_jobs)))
### -> 1356             self.coef_, self.intercept_, n_iter_ = _fit_liblinear(
###    1357                 X, y, self.C, self.fit_intercept, self.intercept_scaling,
###    1358                 self.class_weight, self.penalty, self.dual, self.verbose,

### ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\_base.py in _fit_liblinear(X, y, C, fit_intercept, intercept_scaling, class_weight, penalty, dual, verbose, max_iter, tol, random_state, multi_class, loss, epsilon, sample_weight)
###     924         classes_ = enc.classes_
###     925         if len(classes_) < 2:
### --> 926             raise ValueError("This solver needs samples of at least 2 classes"
###     927                              " in the data, but the data contains only one"
###     928                              " class: %r" % classes_[0])

### ValueError: This solver needs samples of at least 2 classes in the data, but the data contains only one class: 1
```

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: It would be useful to provide some more information about the input data + format the question, s.t. it clearly describes what you are confused about and what you tried to resolve it

Comment: To give a short answer from very limited info -- you probably have data with its labels not having more than one class :) But cannot say without more info

Comment: Please follow [ask] and [mre].

Answer (score 0):

It appears your basic problem here is that you don't fully understand what Logistic Regression does. Very simply, it creates a special regression function to model categorical data.

To solve your immediate problem of getting the algorithm to run you just need make sure your `y_train` has more than one class defined.

To solve the far more important problem of getting introduced to the wonderful world of Generalized Linear Models (GLMs), which includes Logistic Regressions, [I recommend this fantastic course](https://www.coursera.org/learn/regression-models/home/welcome). I took it and learned an enormous amount. I believe it's free if you don't care about getting a certificate at the end. Plus you'll learn a little bit of `R`, which is always good for an aspiring data scientist.